# NSWindow resize limit

Tags: scale, nswindow

I'm trying to create a resize limit for my `NSWindow`. I don't want the window to scale smaller than 732x or 496y pixels. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode click the .xib file and then select your window. In the utilities tray click the size inspector and check the box next to Minimum Size Constraints and set the size

Answer (score 1):

In code you would do it like this:

```
window.contentMinSize = NSMakeSize(320.0, 568.0);
```